# Trello: how to generate an activity report using card list change dates

Tags: api, calendar, report, data-visualization, trello

In an effort to unify and automate my activity report across multiple projects I am trying to generate a timeline-like report from several Trello boards.

An event on the timeline would be generated when a card is moved into the "Doing" list, with the time of list change as the start date.

The end date stays at the current date until the card is moved to the "Done" list at which point it's set to the date on which the activity was completed.

[image: Example of activity timeline]

I've looked at some tools to connect Trello activity to Google Calendar, so far with no success:

- Trello powerups: only provides due dates when connecting to the calendar
- IFTTT - doesn't seem to provide Trello as a recipe source
- Zapier - Only provides due date and last activity dates as source values
- Ducksboard - No template available for this kind of visualisation

Ideally, an "API catalyst" like the ones listed above would be the best solution, alternatively any other suggestion on how to approach the problem using other tools is very welcome (I have a little experience with d3.js).

Comment: To whom it may concern, with a developer friend we've opened a Github project here: https://github.com/taraxe/gantrello

Answer (score 2):

Just do it yourself with their API, you can check [the guide](https://developers.trello.com/get-started/start-building).

Here's my algorithm for a similar task where I show which cards were having that user as a member, so basically it's like "which cards have I been working on yesterday?" report.

1. Connect Trello SDK;
2. Authorize user (only `read` permissions) when he clicks a button (so the popup doesn't get blocked);
3. Fetch /tokens/[token] endpoint to figure out the user's `memberID`;
4. Fetch /members/[memberID]/actions for a required period filtering only by `addMemberToCard,removeMemberFromCard` actions;
5. Run a loop over resulting array to figure out datetime difference between `addMemberToCard` and `removeMemberFromCard` for every card in the response;
6. Format everything and show to the user!

As an example, here's my realization of it: [Trello Activity Report](http://pistonsky.github.io/trello-activity-report/)

Code is here: https://github.com/pistonsky/trello-activity-report

P.S. Instead of using `addMemberToCard` and `removeMemberFromCard` action types, you can filter by `updateCard:idList` and calculate the datetime difference between when card is moved from `To Do` to `Done` list.